# Display next closest div when current selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I want to show next div when current is selected
for ex. when option 1 or 2 selected then drop down of 3 and 4 should be shown, and when 3 or 4 selected then drop down of 5 and 6 should be shown and so on...

Here's what i have done

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var f = $('.abc').first().css("display","block");
  f.change(function() {
    f.next('.abc').css("display","block");
  });
});
```

```css
.abc{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="abc">
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="abc">
    <select>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="abc">
    <select>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="abc">
    <select>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = $('.abc').hide();
  f.first().css("display", "block");
  f.change(function() {
    $(this).next('.abc').css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

First you want `f` to be equal to all `.abc` and not just the first.

Second you need `$(this).next('.abc')` and not `f.next('.abc')`. Because you want to know what `abc` has been changed so you know the next one.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = $('.abc').hide();
  f.first().css("display", "block");
  f.change(function() {
    $(this).next('.abc').css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="abc">
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
    <select>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
    <select>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
    <select>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```